# EF: Parameter postfix in SQL translated from single linq keeps on incrementing

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, parameters

We are facing a production issue with oracle db where the numeric postfix of command parameter in sql issued by EF keeps on increasing when LINQ is being used. For example, when run multiple times, the linq query

`var collection = from obj in Query where obj.Val1==val1 select obj;`

gets translated as (not exact, but sufficient to describe the idea)

`select * from Table1 where Column1=@p__linq__0
select * from Table1 where Column1=@p__linq__1
select * from Table1 where Column1=@p__linq__2
...
select * from Table1 where Column1=@p__linq__1003
...`

As a result, the oracle shared pool cache runs out of memory.

Does anyone have any idea of it?

Comment: due to above behaviour what is your issue now ?

Comment: First off, the above is not a valid LINQ query. Second, if you make it valid by using `obj.Val1 == 1`, then the translated SQL will not contain parameters at all. We could help better if you provide realistic reproducible example (`mcve`)

Comment: @IvanStoev, Hey Ivan, sorry for those mistakes. Actually, the match of `Val1` comes as an argument to a method. I have updated the linq.

Comment: Can't reproduce - EF6.1.3

Comment: Are you using oracle database? Issue is reproducible only with oracle db.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that part. No, I'm not. May be someone else will check that out. Good luck.